# Next js - Import a function from a path that is inside environment variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to import a function which its path is inside an enviroment variable

current import:

import { debug } from '../lib/site-A/utils'

expected import:

import { debug } from process.env.DEBUG_PATH

and in my env.local I have:

DEBUG_PATH=../lib/site-A/utils

I tried this approach but without success.

I am trying to have multiple websites with the same core code. And some dynamic values (constants, titles, colors) will be different

I also found something about dynamic import in next js. But it seems it is more related to components

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: dynamic import might fit you here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: Dynamic import has nothing to do with components. It works for any module.

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, you can't directly use process.env in import statements. Instead, use dynamic imports to load the function based on the environment variable like this:

```
// Your code file where you want to use the function
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const debugImport = dynamic(() => import(process.env.DEBUG_PATH), {
  ssr: false, // This ensures the import is only done on the client-side
});

async function someFunction() {
  const { debug } = await debugImport;
  // Now you can use the 'debug' function as needed.
}
```

In your `.env.local:`

```
DEBUG_PATH=../lib/site-A/utils
```